# Google API - Extracted comments from a google spreadsheet using Python number only 20?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a google spreadsheet with around `3000` rows and I am trying to extract comments from this spreadsheet using the following code:

```
import requests
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient import discovery
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
import httplib2

CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxyyyy"
CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxx"
OAUTH_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
file-id = "zzzzzz"
def retrieve_comments(service, file_id):
  """Retrieve a list of comments.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    file_id: ID of the file to retrieve comments for.
  Returns:
    List of comments.
  """
  try:
    comments = service.comments().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
    return comments.get('items', [])
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
  return None
# ...

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,OAUTH_SCOPE)
flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print("Go to the following link in your web browser "+ authorize_url)
code = input("Enter verfication code : ").strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

comments = retrieve_comments(service, file-id)
```

However, the length of the list `comments` is only `20` whereas the spreadsheet surely contains more comments. Could someone explain which parameter I would need to tweak to retrieve all the comments in the spreadsheet? Thanks!

Comment: Dont use google drive v2.  You should be using v3

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Thanks! I have edited my code. Would you be able to help me with another small question please? I want to link the comment-id with that particular row in the spreadsheet. Do you know of a way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current stage, the default value of `maxResults` (Drive API v2) or `pageSize` (Drive API v3) of "Comments: list" of Drive API v3 is 20. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `However, the length of the list comments is only 20 whereas the spreadsheet surely contains more comments.`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
comments = service.comments().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
return comments.get('items', [])
```

#### To:

From your script, when you want to use **Drive API v2**, please modify it as follows.

```
file_id = "###" # Please set your file ID.

res = []
page_token = None
while True:
    obj = service.comments().list(fileId=file_id, pageToken=page_token, maxResults=100, fields="*").execute()
    if len(obj.get("items", [])) > 0:
        res = [*res, *obj.get("items", [])]
    page_token = obj.get("nextPageToken")
    if not page_token:
        break
return res
```

When you want to use **Drive API v3**, please modify it as follows.

```
file_id = "###" # Please set your file ID.

res = []
page_token = None
while True:
    obj = service.comments().list(fileId=file_id, pageToken=page_token, pageSize=100, fields="*").execute()
    if len(obj.get("comments", [])) > 0:
        res = [*res, *obj.get("comments", [])]
    page_token = obj.get("nextPageToken")
    if not page_token:
        break
return res
```

- In this modification, the all comments in the Spreadsheet is returned as an array.

#### References:

- [Comments: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/list)
- [Comments: list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list)

Comment: I had an another small related question. Please feel free to let me know if you think I should ask this as a separate question. I want to link the comment-id with that particular row in the spreadsheet. Would you know of a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: About your new question of `I want to link the comment-id with that particular row in the spreadsheet.`, I would like to support you. In this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. In that case, please include more information for helping to understand your new question.

Comment: Sure! Will post a new question

Comment: Please feel free to answer this over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75265700/google-drive-api-linking-the-comment-id-of-to-the-row-in-the-spreadsheet